# How to check how many times linux service restarted

Tags: linux, systemctl

Is there a way to check how many times linux service restarted in specific time range? Currently using
`systemctl status nameOfService | grep -Po ".*; \K(.*)(?= ago)"` 
to extract uptime, but it's not enough for diagnostics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have logs from that period, you can indeed extract the "Stopped"/"Started" messages from the logs. On nowadays system with `systemd`, many systems use `journalctl`, but many systems use something else - you'll have to inspect your specific system on how to query the logs.

Your script could look something along:

```
 journalctl --since=<date> --until=<another data> UNIT=<service name> SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=systemd |
 awk '
      /Started/{ started = 1 }
      /Stopped/{ if (started) { started = 0; restarted++; } }
      END {
          print "It was restarted " restarted "times."
      }
 '
```

The regex here are just an example. Better use `journalctl -o json` and parse the output with `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

```
journalctl --since "date" | grep "Starting Some Service" | wc -l
```

`journalctl` to display logs since defined date
`grep` to filter by message accompanying restarting service
`wc -l` to count results

Comment: `grep "Starting Some Service"` note that, that if you have a service that writes that a similar message, like `logger "Reacting to Starting Some Service"`, then the reading would be false - too big. Probably a better matching regex is needed, or additional filtering on `journalctl` side - that's what `UNIT=... SYSLOG_...` stuff are hopefully for.

Comment: You are right, but in my case it's enough - my services writes "Starting serviceName1...", "Starting serviceName2..."